If almost every $x\in E$ is in at least $k$ of $m$ sets, then there's a set with measure at least $\frac{k}{m}\lambda(E)$. (No integration/indicators)

Let $(E_1,\dots,E_m)$ be a finite family of Lebesgue measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $k > 0$ a positive integer. Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set with positive measure. If almost every $x \in E$ belongs to at least $k$ of the $E_j$, show that at least one $E_l$ exists such that $\lambda(E_l) \geq \frac{k}{m}\lambda(E)$.

I'm familiar with an answer to this question using integration (this also). However, I'm looking for a more 'hands on' answer using properties of measure (and without relying on indicators or integration, which really helps us 'count' the number of sets that a point is in). My intuition is that it might involve the principle of inclusion-exclusion, but it also seems tricky to try that out.
Another reason is that I'm curious how this generalizes (or fails to) for non-measurable sets and non-measurable covers, and the indicators/integration approach holds only for measurable functions, which is very opaque.

The key point is to prove $\sum_i \lambda(E_i)\geqslant k\lambda (E)$. And I think the proof based on the indicator and integral with the elegent naive idea behind it is the most natural (and simple) one. If you realize the key idea behind the proof you'll know what I mean. The proof without them is very likely to be more complex and far away from the nature.

It's really helpful to consider the counting measure, which is more simple, instead of Lebesgue measure. BTW, I don't think it can be generalized to non-measurable sets because the result is just about the comparison on the measure of measurable sets.

I expect that we can prove the required claim similarly to my recent answer by the following arguments.
Put $\mathcal E=(E_1,\dots,E_m)$ and $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$. For each subset $A$ of $[m]$ put
$$E_A=\left(E\cap \bigcap_{l\in A} E_l\right) \setminus \bigcup_{l\in [m]\setminus A} E_l.$$
It is easy to see that the family $\{E_A:A\subset [m]\}$ consists of pairwise disjoint sets and $\sum_{A\subset [m]} \lambda(E_A)=\lambda(E)$.
Since almost every $x \in E$ belongs to at least $k$ members of the family $\mathcal E$,
we have that $\lambda(E_A)=0$ for each $A\subset [m]$ with $|A|<k$. Thus
$$\sum_{l=1}^m \lambda(E_l\cap E)=\sum_{A\subset [m]} |A|\lambda(E_A)=\sum_{A\subset [m],\, |A|\ge k} |A|\lambda(E_A)\ge $$
$$\sum_{A\subset [m],\, |A|\ge k} k\lambda(E_A)=k\sum_{A\subset [m],\, |A|\ge k} \lambda(E_A)=$$
$$k\sum_{A\subset [m]} \lambda(E_A)=k\lambda(E).$$
So there exists $l\in [m]$ such that $\lambda(E_l\cap E)\ge \frac km\lambda(E)$.
